# Music 1.0.5.10 on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 not showing 'Up Next' list in Mini Player

Tags: catalina, music.app

I click the 'up next' button, I get history.  I don't see 'up next'.  I see nothing in view, preferences or window menus.  Available docs refer to this as the 'up next' button and do not indicate how to switch from/to history.  Is there a mystery meat UI control I am missing?

In IOS I note that the UI provides a way to switch from history and up next: after scrolling to the bottom of the history list, the 'up next' list appears beneath it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a transient issue.  After rebooting the mac, the mini-player displays  'Playing Next' in green text, to the right of 'History'.